# Refactor same functions with different parent selector jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I am using two functions that do the same thing but have different parent selectors. Unsure how to combine them into one function?

https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/gxxLdx

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    /*---SELECTED ITEM---*/
    $(".entity-selectable").click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('selected-item')) {
            $('.entity-selectable').removeClass('selected-item');
        } 
        $(this).toggleClass('selected-item');

        if ($(this).hasClass("selected-item") && $(".periodicity-selectable").hasClass("selected-item")) {

           $("#hidden-content").addClass("fadeInUp");
        }
    });

    /*---SELECTED ITEM---*/
    $(".periodicity-selectable").click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('selected-item')) {
        $('.periodicity-selectable').removeClass('selected-item');
        } 
        $(this).toggleClass('selected-item');

        if ($(this).hasClass("selected-item") && $(".entity-selectable").hasClass("selected-item")) {

            $("#hidden-content").addClass("fadeInUp");
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just make a combined function, and pass it `this` from click event handler of each class. In the new function just remove class from the siblings of current element. something like this:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    function combinedFunction(element){
        if(!$(element).hasClass('selected-item')) {
            $(element).siblings().removeClass('selected-item');
        } 
        $(element).toggleClass('selected-item');

        if ($(".entity-selectable").hasClass("selected-item") && $(".periodicity-selectable").hasClass("selected-item")) {

           $("#hidden-content").addClass("fadeInUp");
        }

    }
    /*---SELECTED ITEM---*/
    $(".entity-selectable").click(function() {
          combinedFunction(this);
    });

    /*---SELECTED ITEM---*/
    $(".periodicity-selectable").click(function() {
          combinedFunction(this);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That works nicely. I like your calling the same function parsing 'this' from the different parent (class).
I wanted user to not be able to remove a selected item once each parent was selected rather change selection is OK. I tweaked it a bit. Any thoughts about the first 'if'? Better ways to escape the function?

https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/gxxLdx

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most extensible option, but a quick easy way is the following.

```
$(".entity-selectable").click(onClick);
$(".periodicity-selectable").click(onClick);

function onClick() {
        var className = '';
        if ($(this).hasClass('entity-selectable')) {
            className = 'entity-selectable';
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('periodicity-selectable')) {
            className = 'periodicity-selectable';
        }
        if(!$(this).hasClass('selected-item')) {
            $('.'+ className).removeClass('selected-item');
        } 
        $(this).toggleClass('selected-item');

        if ($(this).hasClass("selected-item") && $("." + className).hasClass("selected-item")) {    
           $("#hidden-content").addClass("fadeInUp");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works but I think a small typo with the className = 'entitySelectable';

Comment: I edited it. If you're happy with the answer could you just mark it correct.